# supporting matlab machine learning models through kubeflow pipelines

Tags: matlab, kubernetes, matlab-deployment, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

just trying to figure out if it is possible to create kubeflow pipeline to handle matlab ML scripts.

I am searching the web but it seems nobody asked this question.

I know matlab is dockerizable, but has anyone been able to write KF pipeline for it?

I think KFServing should be the tool, but i do not see anything matlab related

Any suggestion?